# How to secure a windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I have a new Windows 2008 server box coming online in a co-hosted environment. It will host asp.net web applications with sql back-end.

**What is the best way to secure it?**

It will run IIS7 and SQL 2005. The SQL install will only allow Windows authentication. Automatic updates will be enabled.

Should I close certain ports?

I want some sort of protection against DOS attacks and malicious users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you keep on top of the security updates and have a paranoid approach to your firewall you will be fine.

- Lock down connections to specific IP's if possible
- Only open what you need and firewall them off to specific applications or services.
- Have ultra-secure passwords.

If you really feel like being paranoid move RDP away from 3389 and move it to another port.

Answer (score 1):

The best way? After you've got things installed, configured, and running, run the Security Configuration Wizard.