# What steps do you take to secure a windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/11659/what-steps-do-you-take-to-secure-a-debian-server) is my inspiration

i  have windows server  2008R2 in my network as DC.
also i use this server for hosting our organization website.
I want to make it as secure as possible.
What I need to Do for securing my windows server??

***edit***

our Website is run locally and we are Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory for our website.so now what how can i Get the web site off of your Domain Controller???

Comment: Step 1: Get the web site off of your Domain Controller.

Comment: The "duplicate" question has weak answers.

Comment: @joeqwerty:why??

Comment: @longneck: I Read [BeStRaFe answer](http://serverfault.com/a/102126/170966) but it is too Summarized and i need more description also [picflight](http://serverfault.com/users/19181/picflight) server dont have DC

Comment: If you need help with moving your web site from one server to another, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton:Move Website To another server ?? why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pre-Obligatory

- Run a current, supported version of Windows. Currently this is Windows 2008R2 and Windows 2012.
- Never install anything on a domain controller except:

  - DNS, DHCP, WINS, and Certificate Services (and only if needed)
  - Anti-virus, backup agents, monitoring agents

### Obligatory

- Use a core installation if you can
- Rename the local administrator account
- Do not disable the firewall
- Run the [Best Practices Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759260.aspx)
- Run the [Security Configuration Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.03.securitywatch.aspx)
- Use the [Microsoft Security Compliance Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16776) to developy and apply consistent security policies to all your servers
- Do not disable UAC
- Do not install and Roles or Features you aren't actively using.

  - Pay particular attention to un-needed sub-features of roles like IIS
- Keep up to date with OS and application updates

  ### For the paranoid
- Change the RDP port

Comment: tnx for answer but why never install DNS, DHCP, WINS, and Certificate Services Together??( i install it Together for paying Lower cost)

Comment: That is not what I said. You can install dns, dhcp, wins and certificate services on a DC. Those roles are appropriate for a domain controller and have minimalsecurity impact. everything else, like a website, should not be running on a domain controller.

Comment: meh changing the RDP port will just give you a bit less internet background noise.

Comment: Don't forget MS BPA [2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831400.aspx), [2008R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759260.aspx) (other versions available for older versions of Windows, but if you're really concerned about security you probably aren't running ancient software).

Comment: @JesonPark LOL WUT?